# BCP/ Bulk Insert Fails (tab delimited file)

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp, csv

I have been trying to import data (tab delimited) into SQL server. The source data is exported from IBM Cognos. Data can be downloaded from: [sample data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60516851/DIM_Assessment.zip)

I have tried BCP / Bulk Insert, but it did not help. The original datafile contains a header row (which needs to be skipped).

==================================
Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DIM_Assessment](
[QueryType] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[QueryDate] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[APUID] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[AssessmentID] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[ICDCode] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[ICDName] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[LoadDate] [nvarchar](4000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

=============================
Format File generated using the following command

```
bcp [dbname].dbo.dim_assessment format nul -c -f C:\config\dim_assessment.Fmt -S <IP>  -U sa -P Pwd
```

Content of the format file:

```
11.0
7
1       SQLCHAR             0       8000    "\t"     1     QueryType                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       8000    "\t"     2     QueryDate                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       8000    "\t"     3     APUID                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       8000    "\t"     4     AssessmentID                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       8000    "\t"     5     ICDCode                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       8000    "\t"     6     ICDName                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       8000    "\r\n"   7     LoadDate                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

=============================

I tried importing data using BCP / Bulk Insert, however, non of them worked.

```
bcp [dbname].dbo.dim_assessment IN C:\dim_assessment.dat -f C:\config\dim_assessment.Fmt -S <IP>  -U sa -P Pwd

BULK INSERT dim_assessment FROM '\\dbserver\DIM_Assessment.dat'
WITH (
  DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
);
GO
```

Thank you in advance for your help@

Comment: What does "none of them worked" mean? Did you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: Yes, at this time, I cannot import data using SSIS. We are looking at an automated way to import data saved on the network into the SQL server.

Comment: I'm not sure how that reply answers any of my questions.

Comment: @AaronBertrandTes No errors show up. Except it says 0 rows copied.

Comment: When you try the BULK INSERT, that's what happens?

Comment: My bad, I did not see your comment before posting my SSIS thing. sorry.

Comment: This is what I see for bulk insert

Comment: DataFileType will be assumed to be widechar because the data file has a Unicode signature.
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 7. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Answer (score 3):

Your input file is in a terrible format.

Your format file and your `BULK INSERT` command both state that the end of a row should be a carriage return and line feed combination, and that there are seven columns of data. However if you open your CSV file in Notepad you will quickly see that the carriage returns and line feeds are not observed correctly in Windows (meaning they must be something other than precisely `\r\n`). You can also see that there aren't actually seven columns of data, but five:

```
QueryType   QueryDate   APUID   AssessmentID    ICDCode ICDName LoadDate
PPIC    2013-11-20 10:23:14 11431   10963       Tremors
PPIC    2013-11-20 10:23:14 11431   11299       THUMB PAIN
PPIC    2013-11-20 10:23:14 11431   11348       Environmental allergies
...
```

[Just looking at it visually you can tell it isn't right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjH6O.png), and you need to get a better source file before throwing it over the wall at SQL Server and expecting it to handle it smoothly:

> [image]

Comment: I dont know what to say. Probably as others have explained, some columns are missing/ blank, which is why you are seeing the datafile in this bad format?

Answer (score 3):

Just Saved your file as .CSV and bulk inserted with the following statement.

```
BULK INSERT dim_assessment FROM 'C:\Blabla\TestFile.csv'
WITH (
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO
```

**Returned Message**

```
(22587 row(s) affected)
```

**Loaded Data**

[image]

Just notice that some data from ICD name has overflown into LoadDate Column, Just use the `|` pipe character to deliminate and use the same bulk insert statement with `FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'` and happy days .

Comment: It is probably not feasible to add the delimiter (pipe).

Comment: Would you know of a way to save this tab delimited file with "pipes" from command line or something which will not require manual intervention?

Comment: The file was already labeled ".csv" but in tab-delimited format. Do you mean you opened it manually in Excel, and then re-saved it as CSV? Unfortunately you can't do that manually every time. The real fix is to get proper output in the first place, so you don't have to perform manual steps in between...

Comment: @AaronBertrand... so, I have got the data saved as a pipe delimited (all programmatically). So far, I have an issue in saving the data via bcp. I am getting the following error while trying to issue a bcp:
`Starting copy... SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file 21 rows copied. Network packet size (bytes): 4096 Clock Time (ms.) Total : 78 Average : (269.23 rows per sec.)`

Comment: It says 21 rows copied, however, all rows, except first row, first column has some junk values. I am at a loss on what is going on here. It is a simple BCP input with pipe delimiters being specified.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the file via Excel shows the following:

- There are indeed 7 row headers
- Only the first six of them are populated
- Columns 1, 2 and 3 hold identical values
- There is some confusing data, where the fifth column can be either empty, or filled with numbers, or filled with text.

I guess that, in these conditions, bulk insert might not work properly. As Excel seems to manage your file in quite a clean way, you should think about an extra step, from CSV to Excel and then to your database.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I am excited to see this. When you say there should be an extra step, is there a way to save the tab delimited file as a "comma" delimited file in excel, and then, import the data from commandline? If that happens, i am gold!

Comment: You should give this a try through the 'save as' option of Excel. If you can do it manually, it means there's a way to do it programmatically. plain T-SQL might not do the trick, but there is surely some command-line software available. Just google it.

Comment: I am searching! when i find something, will post it here. Thanks

Comment: ok, so i am able to save the file as "csv" using vba. When I import the file using bulk import, it gets imported to the server. However, there is a small problem. 

data in the file (when opened in notepad) shows up:
`PPIC,11/20/2013 10:23,11431,10963,,Tremors ,`
`PPIC,11/20/2013 10:23,11431,11592,,"Glioblastoma, Barin ",`


the first row is inserted correctly. second row inserts, however, the last column is saved into multiple columns (i believe it is because of the extra comma)

How can I fix that?

Comment: If you are using VBA, then I do advise you to go straight with Excel objects and tools and save the file as XLS (or try XML?). This will avoid this coma problem. You can then either go on with VBA and open a recordset based on your XLS file, or switch to an import procedure through SQL Server.

Comment: Another "greasy" solution would be to open your text file and change the coma into another character when the coma is between two quotes ... you'll then be able to get a clean csv file and bulk import it....

Comment: ok, so i managed to get the source data (excel csv delimited) to a pipe delimited using windows powershell. Now, the format file has been updated to use "|" instead of "\t". While trying to do a bcp, I see the error 
`Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in
BCP data-file

21 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 78     Average : (269.23 rows per sec.)`

Any help?

Comment: There is no specific csv format for Excel. If you manage the file through Excel, save it as xml or xlsx. Don't leave it as csv ....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, this was a seemingly simple task to push delimited data from flat-file to SQL server. I thought BCP was the way to go (i used it earlier and was successful).

A quick rundown of what was suggested:
a. fix the source file
b. saving source data in native excel format 
c. saving source data as pipe-delimited data

I tried all the options, but, it was adding multiple steps to my process, but was do-able.

I stumbled upon invoke-sqlcmd & import-csv commandlets from powershell. Turns out, I can import the data using powershell directly. it is a bit slow at this time, but, i can live with that for now.

```
$DATA=IMPORT-CSV dim_assessment.CSV -Delimiter "`t"

FOREACH ($LINE in $DATA)

{
$QueryType="`'"+$Line.QueryType+"`'"
$QueryDate="`'"+$Line.QueryDate+"`'"
$APUID="`'"+$Line.APUID+"`'"
$AssessmentID="`'"+$Line.AssessmentID+"`'"
$ICDCode="`'"+$Line.ICDCode+"`'"
    $ICDName=$Line.ICDName
    $ICDName = $ICDName.replace("'","''")
$ICDName="`'"+$ICDName+"`'" 
$LoadDate="`'"+$Line.LoadDate+"`'"

$SQLHEADER="INSERT INTO [dim_assessment] ([QueryType],[QueryDate],[APUID],[AssessmentID],[ICDCode],[ICDName],[LoadDate])"
$SQLVALUES="VALUES ($QueryType,$QueryDate,$APUID,$AssessmentID,$ICDCode,$ICDName,$LoadDate)"

$SQLQUERY=$SQLHEADER+$SQLVALUES
Invoke-Sqlcmd –Query $SQLQuery -ServerInstance HA -U sa -P Pwd

}
```

Thanks for all your help!